# Algorithm to check unique email taking into account gmail’s +

Tags: algorithm, email, exploit, verify

I have a registration form with a freebie gift and people are misusing it by registering as

```
jo+1@gmail.com
jo+2@gmail.com
```

Are there any standard algorithms that I can run on my email records to verify this scenario?

One where I can take `jo@gmail.com` and invalidate `jo+1@gmail.com`.

Also I don’t know the other symbols like `+` that can be used. Maybe `.`?

**Edit:** Understand that I potentially might have a million emails in my DB to start with

Answer (score 3):

Gmail does not recognize dots in their email addresses. Nor are the addresses case-sensitive.

The plus sign means "ignore everything including and after the +".

So first you want to clean up the email address by stripping out all `.`s. Then detect if there is a `+` or not and if there is, strip out everything between the `+` and the `@`.

Comment: That said, this is just how GMail handles addresses. Use of `+foo` tags on addresses is standardized, but different mail systems will treat case and the presence of `.` differently.